# How to upgrade rest API in docker?

Tags: docker

I have following docker engine and API version.

```
{
    "ApiVersion": "1.17",
    "Arch": "amd64",
    "GitCommit": "a8a31ef",
    "GoVersion": "go1.3.3",
    "KernelVersion": "3.19.0-30-generic",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Version": "1.5.0"
}
```

It shows the Engine version as 1.5.0 but the API version as 1.17. How should I upgrade the API to version 1.21?

I am using ubuntu 15.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installation

API version 1.21 is not released yet, but you can upgrade to 1.20 by following the steps at that url

Comment: Thanks for the reply/ 
How the installation steps mentioned at the link are different from apt-get install docker-engine?

Comment: If you use the standard `apt-get install` you'll be hitting the distribution apt servers.  Using the install instruction you'll hit the docker apt servers. Docker updates their apt servers immediate on every release. Distribution apt servers sometimes lag behind by days or weeks.